# When viewing single parent post, display list of children

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I have a Custom Post Type called `glossary`. I set up `parent` posts called "A", "B", etc. The glossary terms themselves are then set with the appropriate initial as their parent post. So, for example, "abdomen" has the "A" post set as its parent and "protein-skimmer" has the "P" post as its parent.

I now have a list of these initials,

```
<a href="/glossary/a/">A</a>
<a href="/glossary/b/">B</a>
```

When clicking on these links, I'm taken to a view which displays the individual "A" or "B" post.

What I'd like to see instead is "A" as a header, then a list of all of its children posts.

What's the most effective way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it's the most *basic* implementation. It could be more effecient to hook into `pre_get_posts`, and change the query from a 'top level page' to a query for it's children. But that has the potential to break a few things, and in particular would probably require you to alter the template used.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php   //If top level, find children
        if($post->post_parent == 0):
            $children = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type'=>'page',
                'post_parent'=>$post->ID
            ));

            if($children->have_posts()): ?>
                <ul>
                <?php while ( $children->have_posts() ) : $children->the_post(); ?>
                    <li> <?php the_title();?> </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>

            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo 'No children';?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php else://Not top level, display normal post ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endif;?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```