# Single parent post lists child posts with pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

I would like to build on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/43033/6344) so I can incorporate pagination and a couple of other features.

We have over 1,600 entries in our Glossary so certain letters have far more than 20 (my max posts/page) entries.

If a user clicks "A" or accesses "/dev/glossary/a" I'd like them to see a list of all entries with parent "A".

I'd also like:

- The list to be in alphabetical order
- The number of entries for this parent to be displayed at the top of the page
- The list to be paginated

I've had a basic attempt at this using `$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;` and the `paged` argument in the `WP_Query`, but my `next_posts_link` doesn't even display.

I'm not quite sure where to begin with this so any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you're listing all entries, where would the pagination come in?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is, I'd like the user to be able to see 20 entries *at a time*, but I'd like all of the entries to be accessible via the pagination (i.e. click "next page" a few times and the third lot of 20 glossary entries under "A" would be displayed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick for ordering by title, and using pagination:

```
    global $wp_rewrite, $wp_query;
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php   //If top level, find children
        if($post->post_parent == 0):
            $children = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type'=>'page',
                'post_parent'=>$post->ID,
                'paged' => $paged,
                'posts_per_page' => 20,
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order' => ASC
            ));

            if($children->have_posts()): ?>
                <ul>
                <?php while ( $children->have_posts() ) : $children->the_post(); ?>
                    <li> <?php the_title();?> </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>

                $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

                $pagination = array(
                    'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
                    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                    'current' => $current
                );

                if( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
                    $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );

                if( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) )
                    $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) ); ?>

                <?php echo paginate_links( $pagination ); ?>

            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo 'No children';?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php else://Not top level, display normal post ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endif;?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can move the paginate_links function to wherever you want the pagination to go.

As for displaying the total number of entries, you can use the $wp_query variable inside of the loop.

```
<?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

i wrote about creating a custom 'glossary' taxonomy from post titles.  it isn't perfect, but it might be relevant:

http://www.kathyisawesome.com/424/alphabetical-posts-glossary/

it is automatic, but there is not reason you couldn't add a metabox, if the auto-generated letters aren't working quite well enough.

from there i'd probably use the pre_get_posts() hook to force 20 posts/page and alphabetical orderby (kind of can't believe i didn't already have the orderby... should probably update my tutorial at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DaveHunt's answer as well as [this excellent answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/9547/6344), I've been able to put the following code together.

**It's important to note that because the page is_single(), the `paged` variable will always be set to 1.** I spent a lot of time on this because of that oversight on my part!

```
if($post->post_parent == 0):

    if ( get_query_var( 'tpage' ) > 0 )
        $paged = get_query_var( 'tpage' );
    else
        $paged = 1;

    $base = trailingslashit( get_permalink( $post->ID ) );

    $children = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'=>'glossary',
        'post_parent'=>$post->ID,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => ASC
    ) );

    if ( $children->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php while ( $children->have_posts() ) : $children->the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'list', 'glossary' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php

            $links = array(
                'base' => $base . 'tpage/%#%',
                'total' => $children->max_num_pages,
                'current' => $paged
            );

        ?>

        <div class="navigation">
            <?php echo paginate_links( $links ); ?>
        </div>

    <?php else: ?>
        Sorry, there are no entries in our glossary for this letter.
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
```

Hope this helps any other users coming across a similar problem.